# solr/elasticsearch search request is handled by shards or replica?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

I have designed solr/elasticsearch for searching, I have a particular question. suppose I have 10K search request/seconds. so where will be my search on Shards or replica. I know replica is backup of shards.

if it happens on shards then how/why and if its on replica then how/why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primary Shard is the original copy of data, while the replica shard is a copy of your original data.

While Indexing always happens on the original copy ie primary shards and then copied to replica shards, but the search can happen on any of the copy irrespective of original or copy of data.

Hence replicas are not only created for fault-tolerance where if you lose one copy, it can recover from copy of it, **But also to improve the search performance where if one shard is overloaded (primary or replica) then search happens on the least loaded copy ie another replica.**

Please refer to [Adaptive replica selection in ES](https://www.elastic.co/blog/improving-response-latency-in-elasticsearch-with-adaptive-replica-selection) on how/why replicas improve the search latency.

Feel free to let me know if you need more information.

**EDIT based on OP comment**:

From ES 7 adaptive replica selection is by default on, so it would send to a least loaded replica but even if all shards are underutilized still it wouldn't send all search requests to primary shards to avoid overloading it. Also before ARS(adaptive replica selection), ES used to send these search requests on round-robin fashion to avoid overloading one shard.

Comment: It means when cluster is stable all request is single handled by shards and it does not pass any request to replica.

Comment: @shiv, ES can send search request to any shard it can be primary or replica, from ES 7 adaptive replica selection is by default on, so it would send to a least loaded replica but coming to your question, even if all shards are underutilized still it woundn't send all search request to primary shards as before ARS(adaptive replics selection) ES used to send these search requests on round robin fashion to avoid overloading one shard, also indexing request always first goes to primary shard, hence its simple that ES wouldn't want to send more request to it, whether its overloaded or not.

Comment: @shiv, Glad I could help here :)

Comment: thanks @Opster ES Ninja really appriciate your help.